# JAVA 9 + spring-boot 2.0 + maven 3.5.3, meet ERROR package com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers is not visible

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, java-9, maven-compiler-plugin

I execute spring-boot:run command successfully in java 9 + spring-boot 2.0 + maven 3.5.3.
I want to migrate project java 7 to java 9. My project has many library dependencies, and compiles by java 6 or 7. I know internal api is a problem.
So I added a class for testing and run it. It failed like below error.

> package com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers is not visible
>     (package com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers is declared in module java.xml, which does not export it)

So I added compilerArgs option in maven-compiler-plugin.(Because com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers package is inaccessible by default)  But error still occurs.

```
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <executions>
                ...
                        <compilerArgs>
                            <compilerArg></compilerArg>
                            <arg>--add-exports</arg>
                            <arg>java.xml/com.sun=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                        </compilerArgs>
                ...
            </executions>
```

Maven debug log is this.

> [DEBUG] -d ... -classpath ... -g -parameters -nowarn -target 9 -source 9 -encoding UTF-8 --add-exports java.xml/com.sun=ALL-UNNAMED

And my test class is like this.

```
package com.naver.blog.jdk9.upgradetest;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser;

public class TestSaxParser extends SAXParser {
    ...
}
```

Comment: `--add-exports java.base/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers=ALL-UNNAMED` will work as a temporary workaround but you really need to fix the code that is using this JDK-internal API.

Comment: @AlanBateMan 
I really appreciate your answer. it works fine. 
I wonder many libraries compiled by jdk 7 or 8 is running well on jdk 9 except this internal api issue?
I try to solve the problem by adding dependencies to pom.xml.